# Running docker as sibling

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a container (`hello-world`) as a sibling from another container (`dev`).

But, container script is not able to access "Docker". I am getting

> Docker not found error

Here is what I am doing: `dev` *Dockerfile* downloads the docker image Like

```
ENV DOCKER_VERSION=19.03.8
RUN curl -sfL -o docker.tgz 
"https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" && \
  tar -xzf docker.tgz docker/docker --strip=1 --directory /usr/local/bin && \
  rm docker.tgz

RUN ["chmod","+x","./script.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","./script.sh"]
```

*script.sh* is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
docker run hello-world
```

Docker Build command:

```sh
docker build -t dev .
```

Docker run command:

```sh
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <container_image>
```

Comment: So you are trying to install docker in a docker container? Why don't you use the [`docker`](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image for that?

Comment: In the image, what kind of file is `/usr/local/bin/docker`?  If it has shared-library dependencies, are they also installed in the image?  What's the base image?  @β.εηοιτ.βε's suggestion to use the `docker` image is still reasonable if you want to reuse the host Docker daemon; the `docker:latest` image doesn't try to launch a separate daemon.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε,   yes. I am trying to install docker in a docker container.  How to use docker  image for this ?

Comment: @David, when I run "RUN ls -la /usr/local/bin/*" in dockerfile, it is not showing docker image. is there any issue with curl command ?